# Spring boot security antMatchers and Sonarlint vulnerability

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, sonarlint

I am confused with the following spingboot security config and a Critical Vulnerability raised by Sonalint.
Is there a way to simplify the configuration to avoid the error ?

"HttpSecurity" URL patterns should be correctly ordered
Reorder the URL patterns from most to less specific, the pattern "/api/supervision/**" should occurs before "/api/supervision/**".

```
   http
        .authorizeRequests()
             .and()
        .requestMatchers()
             .antMatchers(WebUtils.SUPERVISION_API_PATH + "/**", WebUtils.EXTERNAL_API_PATH + "/**")
             .and()
         .httpBasic()
             .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
             .and()
         .sessionManagement()
             .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)               
             .and()
         .csrf()
             .disable()
         .authorizeRequests()
             .antMatchers(WebUtils.SUPERVISION_API_PATH + "/**").hasAuthority(AUTHORITY_USER)
             .antMatchers(WebUtils.EXTERNAL_API_PATH + "/**").hasAnyAuthority(AUTHORITY_API, AUTHORITY_ADMIN);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are the values of `WebUtils.SUPERVISION_API_PATH` and `WebUtils.EXTERNAL_API_PATH`?

Comment: SUPERVISION_API_PATH = /api/supervision and EXTERNAL_API_PATH= / api/external

Comment: There is no need for multiple `.authorizeRequests()` blocks. You can remove the first ` .authorizeRequests().and()`